# Undefined Constructor, but I have a default Contructor?

Tags: java

Eclipse says this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     The constructor Car(String, String, int) is undefined   The
>   constructor Car(String, String, int) is undefined     The method
>   getCarInfo() is undefined for the type Car    The method getCarInfo() is
>   undefined for the type Car
>
> at CarDriver.main(CarDriver.java:5)

and this is my driver:

```
public class CarDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c1 = new Car("Nissan", "Z31", 175);
        Car c2 = new Car("Honda", "Prelude", 145);

        System.out.println(c1.getCarInfo());
        System.out.println(c2.getCarInfo());
    }
}
```

And this is my class:

```
public class Car {

    /*
     * Car class is a method to make a car with make and model of
     * String and odometer of int to reflect how fast or how far
     * the odometer reads, I guess.
     */

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int odometer;          

    public Car() {  //This is the default constructor for the Car.
        make = "Toyota";
        model = "Supra"; //My favorite car, especially the 80s ones. (*•̀ᴗ•́*)و ̑̑
        odometer = 225;
    }

    public Car(String make, String model, int odometer) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.odometer = odometer;
    }

    public void setMake(String manufacturer) {
        this.make = manufacturer;
        System.out.println("The car is made by" + this.make);
    }

    public void setModel(String type) {
        this.model = type;
        System.out.println("The car is a " + this.model);
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.odometer = speed;
        System.out.println("The car goes " + this.odometer + " KPH");
    }

    public String getCarInfo() {
        String carDescription = "The car is a " + model + " made by " + make + " and goes " + odometer + " KPH";
        return carDescription;
    }
}
```

Not really sure went wrong
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please don't confuse a default constructor with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Do you have more than one `Car` class in your project?

Comment: That code compiles without error. `Car` must not have been compiled since you made changes to it, or something like that.

Comment: You seem to have done everything right. Are your class and driver files in the same directory? You may have to do some imports if that's not the case.

Comment: Compiles fine in mine.

Comment: Does `CarDriver.java` have any import statements? (If it does, show them)

Comment: first of all dump Eclipse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Eclipse might be confused.  Sometimes IDEs get partial builds kind of stuck in memory and can't seem to clear them.  I know this sounds like a cop-out, but have you tried tell Eclipse to clean, shutting down Eclipse completely, starting it up again, and tell it to do a full rebuild?  I do this when things quit making sense.  I've had to do it less since changing IDEs, but it still happens sometimes.

Oh, another possibility (unlikely, but possible):  Could you maybe have a compiled earlier version of your classes in a place where Eclipse is picking it up as a library?  If you're doing a mix of command-line work and Eclipse work, this could happen.  Tell it to ignore any build directories not under its control, and check its imports for anything suspicious.

Comment: I just started using Eclipse (my school requires it, I came from BlueJ), and just opening it up today. Did the trick.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Glad I could help!  My favorite is IntelliJ, which I switched to on my first coding job after Eclipse bricked my workspace for about the third time in four weeks.